# Windows 8 theme?

Tags: windows-7, themes, windows-8-preview

Where can i get the Windows 8 themes? I've googling for this but, not yet get it. If i've anything means, then, it's not downloading for me. For examples -

[Windows 8 theme](http://windows8themes.org/download2.php?download=download2/freewindows8themes.zip)

[Windows 8 theme for Windows 7](http://technojourney.com/windows/free-windows-theme-pack-windows-download/)

All these links, telling me `Thank you for downloading` But, not yet downloaded. I'm using Windows 7. Anyone having this means, give me the link to download that.

Comment: The downloads work fine here. Had to wait for 30secs or so

Comment: Do you want themes to make Windows 7 look like Windows 8, or are you trying to download themes for Windows 8 on a Windows 7 machine?

Comment: I'm trying to download themes for Windows 8 on a Windows 7 Machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search on deviantart.com. A lot of stuff there. You need metro style themes. Some groups:

- http://microsoftmetrolovers.deviantart.com/
- http://metro-design.deviantart.com/
- http://microsoftmetrolovers.deviantart.com/gallery/26106412
- http://microsoftdesign.deviantart.com/